# PS command doesn´t show a running php process

Tags: php, linux

I´m using ps command to check if a php script (called test.php) is running. The command is "ps aux | grep test.php".

If try to run test.php from the command line in my server everything works as expected. But when i call the same script from a browser (http://my_server.com/test.php) the ps command doesn't show the process.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: That's because `Apache` handled the request and opened up the interpreter to interpret the contents of the file. in the `php-cli`, that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to know if the script is being run from the interpreter?